# Names are not displaying on csv from dataframe in python but do in console

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

So this piece of code will display everything when run in the console, the team name plus win, lose, draw and all the info I want but .. When I save to csv all the columns and rows are in order but the only thing missing are the name of the teams. What am I doing wrong?

```
def team_stats():

    def initialise_teams_dataframe():
        init_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
        init_dataframe['teams'] = ''

        first_part = ['last_month', 'this_month', 'all_time']
        second_part = ['win', 'draw', 'loss']
        column_titles = []

        for first in first_part:
            for second in second_part:
                column_titles.append(first + '_' + second)

        for column_title in column_titles:
            init_dataframe[column_title] = 0

        return init_dataframe

    data = initialise_teams_dataframe()
    i = 0

    for team_links in get_all_team_links(URL, BASE_URL):

        rest_server(True)
        page = requests.get(team_links).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

        team_name_element = soup.select_one('div.teamNameHolder')
        team_name = team_name_element.find('h1').text.replace('- Team Overview', '')

        for statistics in soup.select('table.stats-table'):

            second_most_recent_month = [th.text.strip() for th in statistics.select_one("tr + tr + tr")
                                        if isinstance(th, Tag)][1]

            most_recent_month = [th.text.strip() for th in statistics.select_one("tr + tr + tr")
                                 if isinstance(th, Tag)][2]

            all_time_stats = [th.text.strip() for th in statistics.select_one("tr + tr + tr")
                              if isinstance(th, Tag)][3]

            last_month_wdl = second_most_recent_month.split('/')
            this_month_wdl = most_recent_month.split('/')
            all_time_wdl = all_time_stats.split('/')

            row = [team_name] + last_month_wdl + this_month_wdl + all_time_wdl
            data.loc[i] = row

            print(data)
            data.to_csv('test.csv')
            i += 1  # This runs last!
```

Comment: Why are you using pandas, just to write to a csv?

Comment: Well I guess I don't really know how to, I was shown this method by a friend. So it's all I know..Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: There are simpler ways to do what you want, try this http://pastebin.com/2dZ9Nshc, obviously adding in your own functions and imports

Comment: ok, but thus far the only problem is that the team names are not appearing on the csv, everything else though is fine. So I am not sure what I did wrong

Comment: There is an awful lot going on in your code, try the code and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I tried it, it writes the csv but not the data, ill try a few other things

Comment: Can you add the full code?